# Redireccionar a un HTML cuando llamada AJAX da 200/OK

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, nodejs, formularios

Como va comunidad ?
Les explico la consulta brevemente. Tengo un form de inicio de sesion que quiero cuando la llamada GET con Ajax (Usando fetch) devuelva un Status 200 o que se completo correctamente (Es decir, que reconozca que el mail ingresado esta en la base de datos), me redireccione a otro documento HTML que esta en la misma carpeta del proyecto (Que en este caso seria el "HOME" de la pagina).
Estuve buscando por developer mozilla los tipos de response.redirect que hay, pero ninguno aclara la duda de como hacerlo.

***Codigo del form***

```
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 container-form">
            <form action="/user/login" method="GET" id="form"> 
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="email" class="etiqueta">E-Mail</label>
                  <input type="emai" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Ingresa tu Email" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="password" class="etiqueta">Contraseña</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
                </div>
                <br>
                <button type="submit" id="boton-inicia" class="btn btn-primary">Inicia Sesion</button>
              </form>
              <div class="col-12 registro">
                <span class="texto">¿No sos usuario? ¡Registrate!</span>
                <br>
                <a href="sing-up.html"><button type="click" id="boton-registrate" class="btn btn-success">Registrate</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

***Codigo JS***

```
    // Funcion de envio
    iniciaSesion = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Declaro la constante
    const host = 'http://localhost:3000/user/login';

    // Declaro una constante que va a obtener los valores de los inputs
    const form = {
        email: document.getElementById("email").value,
        password: document.getElementById("password").value
    };

    if (form.email === '', form.password === ''){
        UI.mostrarAlerta('Por favor, ingrese todos los datos', 'danger');
    } else { 
        // Declaro su end-point, metodo + envio en JSON
        fetch(host, {
        method: 'GET',
        body: JSON.stringify(form),
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        }
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log("Respuesta =", response);
            return response.text();
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        })
    }
};

// Llamo al boton y le agrego su evento y defino la funcion
document.getElementById("boton-inicia").addEventListener('click', iniciaSesion);
```

Answer (score 0):

Desde Javascript se redirige con:

```
window.location.href='nueva url aquí';
```